# Count length of String excluding linebreaks

Tags: java

I am writing out a String and i need it to break the lines every time there is 20 characters on a line.
However, it counts the

```
\n
```

as a character as well. How can i break the lines when there is 20 characters on the line, excluding the \n?

Edit: Every time it've counted 20 characters, it adds \n to the end of the line

Comment: What's the code you currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before printing your string, get rid of the containing line breaks like this:

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Here `"\\n"` is a regular expression matching the newline character. The string literal `"\\n"` is actually a string containing `\n`

Answer (score 1):

You could first find and replace with an empty string all the occurences of "\n" into your source then execute your algorithm.

```
destinationSring = sourceString.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Comment: I'm really new to java, could you perhaps extend your answer to include an example of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
stringValue.replaceAll("[\n\r]+", "").length()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
for (char c : someString.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '\n') continue;
    System.out.print(c);
    ++count;
    if (count % 20 == 0) System.out.println();    
}
```